# Read the output of "date +%Z" in an Ubuntu terminal into R

Tags: r, timezone, ubuntu-12.04

I would like to read the timezone of an Ubuntu Server into an R character class object for an R Shiny Application.  If I type:

```
date +%Z
```

into my Ubuntu terminal, I get

```
EDT
```

How might I read this into R?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `pipe`

```
> con <- pipe("date +%Z")
> readLines(con)
[1] "CEST"
```

that on your system shoud give `"EDT"`